# Using map to create an object of concatenated list items in R

Tags: r, purrr

I've created a dummy function using the Iris dataset, so (hopefully) it is reproducible.

I have a function that returns a list of results, and I then run several terms with this function, and concatenate them into a list.  I want to try and do this with map, but I'm not having much success.

This function basically returns a list:

```
my_func <- function(spec) {
    specl <- grep(spec, iris$Species)

    full <- c()
    for (s in specl) {
        nam <- iris$Species[s]
        leng <- iris$Sepal.Length[s]
        lenglist <- list(leng) %>%
            setNames(str_c("val: ", nam, s))
        full <- c(full, lenglist)
    }
    return(full)
}

my_result <- c(
    my_func("setosa"),
    my_func("virginica")
)

head(my_result, 2)
$`val: setosa1`
[1] 5.1

$`val: setosa2`
[1] 4.9


length(my_result)
[1] 100
```

I'd like to use `purrr:::map` to make this result object.  I tried this:

```
terms <- c("setosa", "virginica")
my_result_with_map <- terms %>%
    map(~my_func(.x))
```

But the result is listing each term as a separate list item:

```
> head(my_result_with_map)
[[1]]
[[1]]$`val: setosa1`
[1] 5.1
  
[[1]]$`val: setosa2`
[1] 4.9
  
[[1]]$`val: setosa3`
[1] 4.7

...

length(my_result_with_map)
[1] 2
```

Is this possible to recreate the original `my_result` object using map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` returns a `list` while in the first case, we are using `c` to concatenate the output.  Either `invoke` with `c` or use `flatten`

```
my_result_with_map <- terms %>%
    map(~my_func(.x))  %>%
    flatten
```

-output

```
> head(my_result_with_map, 2)
$`val: setosa1`
[1] 5.1

$`val: setosa2`
[1] 4.9
```